# Setting background Image to uitableview?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, uitableview

I want to set an image as the background for my `uitableview`. This is the code I am using:

```
 self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_tableview.png"]];
```

This is showing the image right but as soon as the table is populated something weird happens. Parts of images are shown in each `tableviewcell` and also the image scrolls along with the table. How can I make it so that the image remains fixed and that each `tableviewcell` doesn't show part of the image?

Thanks,
 
TC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView cell with background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329832/uitableview-cell-with-background-image)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't want to set the background of the `UITableView` if you don't want it to scroll. Instead, you want to set the background of the `UITableView` to be transparent - and provide your own fixed background behind the `UITableView`.

To do this, first set the background of the UITableView to "Clear Color".

**Programmatically:** `self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

You'll also want to un-check the opaque checkbox.

**Programmatically:** `self.tableView.opaque = NO;`

Setup the fixed background you want in the view behind the `UITableView`.

Make sure any sub-views in any of your `UITableViewCell`s are also `backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` (`UITextView`s, etc.)

[image: Example Xcode 4 / Interface Builder setup]

Comment: any way to do it problematically?

Comment: Edited with sample code to do it programmatically (not sure about `problematically` though... hehe). You'll have to take it from there. Anything you can do in interface builder you can do through code - and fairly straight-forwardly. Just search Apple's documentation for the class name and the name of the property you're looking for. You'll find it.

Comment: do I have to add the uiimageview as subview?

Comment: Just set the backgroundcolor for the uiview instead of the uitableview like you are now.

Comment: Good explaination:) 1up for ans

Answer (score 7):

Image for the TableView background

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image"]];
```

Do not forget write the file name with the image's type. EXAMPLE:

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myPhoto.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution works if inside a `UIViewController`, you add a `tableView` and `Imageview`
In the code, create an outlet of the `tableView` and connect it to the `tableView` in xib, connect the view to the `UIView`. Put an image to the `UIImageView` and click on the `imageView`. Select:

> Editor >Arrange > Send to Back

In `viewDidLoad` method of the `UIViewController`, add the following lines:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.opaque = NO;
```

and it worked for me:)

Answer (score 0):

/* set Backgroundimage in uitableview as follows*/

```
UIImageView *imguser = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user"]];
[tblUser setBackgroundView:imguser];
```