# How to set Background image in UITableView cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have Created custom cell.And i have table view with Grouped style.Now i want to put Backgroung image to each cell of different section.How to set the background image of custom cell.
Here is the code for creating the custom cell.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 305, 90)];
```

//  view.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];

```
UIImageView *imageV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 9, 61, 55)];
// NSLog(@"imageArray%@",[play.imageArray count]);
NSString *img=[play.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"img=%@",img);
imageV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:img];
[view addSubview:imageV];
[imageV release];

UILabel *lblAchievementName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 10, 168, 21)];
lblAchievementName.text = [play.listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
lblAchievementName.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

lblAchievementName.textColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
[lblAchievementName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Black" size:16.5]];

[view addSubview:lblAchievementName];
[lblAchievementName release]


[cell.contentView addSubview:view];

return cell;
```

Now how to set the backgroung image for this custom view?

Comment: how many section do you have in your table view?

Comment: Look at this my previous answer  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329832/uitableview-cell-with-background-image/6330427#6330427

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try this code that will help you.

Put this code in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method

```
   UIImageView *av = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 277, 58)];
    av.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    av.opaque = NO;
    av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"categorytab1.png"];
    cell.backgroundView = av;
```

Comment: for future visitors- when using grouped UITableView style, that approach will remove the boarder, which some people may want. To avoid that just do: [cell setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"categorytab1.png"]]];

Comment: Making backgroundView transparent is not useful since there's nothing behind. Better do this:

`cell.textLabel.opaque = NO;
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Comment: You probably want to called [UIImage imageNamed:...] in an init method (initWithStyle:, of if you're using storyboard prototype cells, initWithCoder:) so that you're not allocating new images all over the place.

Answer (score 3):

set thru setBackgroundView method.Form the ImageView with ur need Image aand set that as,

```
[cell setBackgroundView:urBgImgView];
```

Comment: Can I set an image as tableView background, not for individual cells of the tableView

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code for different image in different section.

```
UIImageView *imageV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 9, 61, 55)];
// NSLog(@"imageArray%@",[play.imageArray count]);
NSString *img=[play.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"img=%@",img);
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    imageV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:img0];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    imageV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:img1];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    imageV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:img2];
}

[view addSubview:imageV];
[imageV release];
```

Answer (score 0):

i'd rather to add a CALayer or UIImageView to be the backgroud view. Because i used to set the BackgroundColor, but it never workd for me. so i changed my mind by this way.