# Can UITableViewCell´s ImageView cover the whole background?

Tags: ios, ios6, uikit

I´m build a swipe feature for my todo-list application. When a user swipes(drag) the cell horizontally I would like to display a background image that covers the gap between the screen edge and the cell edge.

When I add an image to the imageView-property it just follows the cell. Can I somehow fix it to cover the whole background?

Comment: Does this work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775859/how-to-set-background-image-in-uitableview-cell

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make something like **Clear**.

What you will need to do is:

- Subclass `UITableViewCell`
- Add your image view like this..

  ```
  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
  imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
  imageView.image = myImage;
  [self insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0]; //I'm not at a compiler, so I'm not 100% on this, but it's something like this.
  ```
- Add a `UIGestureRecognizer` to handle gestures, and set up dragging and appropriate actions.