# change cell background

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to change uitableview cell background image?

I write this code, it's not working. but I am sure this code some minor mistake.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        [cell setBackgroundView:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-bg.png"]];
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329832/uitableview-cell-with-background-image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the `UIImage` in a `UIImageView` before you can set it as a `backgroundView`:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-bg.png"]] autorelease];
[cell setBackgroundView:imageView];
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the incorrect parameter to `setBackgroundView:` function of `UITableViewCell` .. It expect either instance of `UIView` or any instance inherited from `UIView`.

```
UIImageView * myImage = [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-bg.png"]];
[cell setBackgroundView:myImage];
[myImage release];
```