# UITableViewCell background image not displaying

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, background-image

I am trying to add a background image to `UITableViewCell` using the following code:

```
UIImage *bgImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"green-cell-row.png"];
UIImageView *bgForFirst=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImage];
cell.backgroundView=bgForFirst;
[cell.contentView addSubview:venueDisplayImage];
[cell.contentView addSubview:venueDisplayName1];
[cell.contentView addSubview:venueDisplayName2];
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

However, I get venueDisplayName on white space around it. What would be the best way to fix this and correctly add my background image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329832/uitableview-cell-with-background-image/6330427#6330427

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

1) TabelView set the background like:

```
tblView.backgroundView.alpha = 0.0;
tblView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

2) Add the image view in cellForRowAtIndexPath og delegate method of tableview:

```
UIImageView *bckView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 300,80)];
cell.backgroundView.alpha = 0.0;
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
bckView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"];
bckView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
[cell.contentView addSubview:bckView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change `backgroundColor` or `venueDisplayName` to `[UIColor clearColor]` or to `[UIColor greenColor]`?

For performance reasons try to avoid using non-opaque views in `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: no venueDisplayName is UILabel and I initialize it with a frame then adding it to a cell

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the property of cell
there are 2 property you can use 
1) cell.backgroundColor
2) cell.backgroundView

```
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageName:@""]];
```

In second case you have to set any view as a background view