# UITableViewCell's background image's height won't smoothly follow the row's height

Tags: ios, uitableview

We had create a `UITableviewController` to list some contents,
We want an effect that the background image view will smoothly expand follow as the row's height changing, but we just got the effect with image changed to the final height of row.

the video is what we got:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-5TtrpYhl8

in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, we just add a subview too the cell as below

```
UIImage *cellBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbg.png"];
UIImageView *cellBackgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[cellBackgroundImageView setImage:[cellBackgroundImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10]];
[cell addsubview:cellBackgroundImageView]
```

than just set height in the `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` like `return 50` or `return 250`

But there obviously some fault around here, how can I fix it? I had google all around, and some apps do this kind of effect (like "DOOO"), I will appreciate you're answers!

---

we had try other methods like add `UIImageView` height changing in a custom `UITableViewCell`'s `layoutSubview` method, that's work the same as the video above

---

Thank You for CSmith's answer, we had tried this method for background, but we found our problem is not on background, we'll keep finding our solution, but thank you~~ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [UITableView cell with background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329832/uitableview-cell-with-background-image)

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:10.0] ];
```