# Setting cell rounded corner and border width makes tableview scrolling extremely slow

Tags: ios, uitableview, quartz-graphics

I'd like to round the corner of my tableview cells and make the gap between them bigger.

I do it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath like this:

```
static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"normal";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(cell == nil)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

CALayer* layer = cell.layer;
[layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
[layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
```

By calling setBorderWidth scrolling of tableview becomes extremely slow. Without it it works like a charm.

So, how can I make cell cornder rounding and set border width faster?

Comment: This works perfectly.  Any idea on how to make this work for a cell's imageView.layer?

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of times to make it work fast. But it works really slow when is used for many objects.

What can i recomend:

To use background image, not to use layer properties. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329832/uitableview-cell-with-background-image) for example

Or to use tableView style - `UITableViewStyleGrouped`

In your case may be it is not a large amount of objects in the table view, so optimize it for example with setting border when you create the cell :

```
if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

CALayer* layer = cell.layer;
[layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
[layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
}
```

Comment: I have only a few elements, about 30, and my iphone5 is struggling with it

Comment: Really a lot, better create background image or use grouped table view. It would work like a charm.

Comment: I mean 30 elements in the list, I think it is very few

Comment: More that 10 usually makes ui slow down on device, with simulator everthing should be ok. It's because it always has to redraw cell's layer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting your layer properties every time, just do it once when the cell is created like so.

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

CALayer* layer = cell.layer;
[layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
[layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
}
```

Comment: Cell is defined on storyboard, so it does not matter.