# How make background image in tableViewCell

Tags: ios, tableview, uitableview

I have my tableView. But i have some problem with image in tableViewCell. Background color displayed only in the left and right corner but in the middle color from all background my tableView. When i changed background color in my table also changed color in the middle of my tableViewCell...

My cod for add image in tableViewCell:
When will push...

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"noselected.png"]stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];
```

and pushed. Pushed displayed okey.

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"yesselected.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];
```

Also: I tried UIColour cleareColor but nothing.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329832/uitableview-cell-with-background-image

Comment: post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method code.

Comment: Thanks it's all work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

If you want to display only one image for each cell.

```
   cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"name_of_the_image_AND_no_need_to write_extension"]];
```

If you want to display different image for different cell

**first create a image array** to save all those images that you need to display in cells..

```
 imgArr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"],
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"],
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3"],
                                          nil];
```

then, in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[imgArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```